# How detect if eg. T::is_transparent is defined?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Is there a generic template/Macro for testing eg. if name is defined, something ala. how [`is_transparent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) works.

`is_transparent` makes the *comparator* transparent for `std::set` (ie. can lookup/etc. with custom types). It just needs to be defined to whatever, eg. `using is_transparent = void;`

Im looking to do something similar for some custom types, but ideally I would use something (a macro even) from [std](/questions/tagged/std) or [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) or I could use guidance on the implementation.

**The question is, how to test if type is defined (exists?) based on qualified name ?**

Comment: You need to make a type trait.  There are plenty of questions already on the site on how to write one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the detection idiom:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/type_traits>

struct A {};

struct B
{
    using is_transparent = void; // Any other type works too.
};

template <typename T> using detect_transparent = typename T::is_transparent;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<detect_transparent, A> << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << std::experimental::is_detected_v<detect_transparent, B> << '\n'; // 1
}
```

`is_detected_v` is an experimental feature from so-called [library fundamentals TS v2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions_2).

If your compiler doesn't support it, or you don't like seeing the word `experimental` in your code, you can implement it yourself:

```
namespace impl
{
    template <typename T, typename ...P>
    struct dependent_type {using type = T;};

    // `std::void_t` used to be broken in Clang (probably it no longer is),
    // so I use a custom safe replacement instead.
    template <typename A, typename ...B>
    using void_type = typename dependent_type<void, A, B...>::type;

    template <typename DummyVoid, template <typename...> typename A, typename ...B>
    struct is_detected : std::false_type {};

    template <template <typename...> typename A, typename ...B>
    struct is_detected<void_type<A<B...>>, A, B...> : std::true_type {};
}

template <template <typename...> typename A, typename ...B>
inline constexpr bool is_detected_v = impl::is_detected<void, A, B...>::value;
```

Comment: Is it really part pf c++20? I found it is "listed" under "Library fundamentals v2" but *not* merged into C++20. Not important as your solution given here is quite perfect :-)

Comment: @Klaus Huh, apparently not. Thanks, I've fixed the wording. :)